# Перемещение вектора, возвращенного из функции (C++)

Tags: c++, функции, return, copy, move

Подскажите, будет ли перемещен вектор, возвращенный из функции, или произойдет копирование содержимого:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

struct my_type
{
  int data1;
  int data2;
};

vector<my_type> test_func(int i, int j)
{
  vector<my_type> result {{i, j}, {j, i}};

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  vector<my_type> vec_mt;
  //...
  vec_mt = test_func(1, 2); /* <---- MOVE or COPY ???
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копирования точно не будет.

В худшем случае будет перемещен два раза, в лучшем случае - один.

Если написать `vector<my_type> vec_mt = test_func(1, 2);`, то в худшем случае будет одно перемещение, а в лучшем - ноль.

---

Сам возврат локальной переменной из функции по значению либо использует NRVO, если компилятор достаточно умный (ноль перемещений), либо перемещение. [Источник](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes).

Вот такое присвоение `vec_mt = test_func(1, 2);` - одно перемещение.

Инициализация `vector<my_type> vec_mt = test_func(1, 2);` - в C++17 ноль перемещений, из-за [обязательного RVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: Вот статья с исследованием темы Copy elision (пропуск копий) https://habr.com/ru/post/277333/

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от используемого стандарда: дело в том, что 11 стандарда был введен `copy elision` - это означает что при подобном возврате из функции копирования не произойдет. Однако до 17 стандарта там существовали некоторые ограничения на `copy elision`, например возвращаемую переменную следовало объявлять первой, а иначе содержимое может быть скопировано. С 17-ого эти ограничения были сняты